# Qml strange behavior with cyrillic symbols

Tags: windows, qt, qml

I am experiencing very strange behavior with cyrillic letters. I'm using Qt 5.12.6, Windows 10 (64 bit).

The whole application wrote with QML, as you can see some words don't make any sense they are not Russian. All QML Text elements behave the wrong way.

[image: application window]

The top login buttons underlied red look like this

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Button {
    id: loginPageButton
    font.capitalization: Font.AllUppercase
    checkable: true
    flat: true

    contentItem: Text {
        text: loginPageButton.text
        font: loginPageButton.font
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        elide: Text.ElideRight
    }
}
```

using

```
LoginPageButton {
    id: newAccountButton
    text: qsTr("CREATE AN ACCOUNT")
    font.pixelSize: 16
    ButtonGroup.group: btnGroup
    checked: false
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
}
```

retranslate is made in such way

```
QGuiApplication::removeTranslator(&m_currentTranslator);
bool isLoaded = m_currentTranslator.load(QString("tr_%1").arg(locale), QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/translations/");
if (isLoaded)
    QGuiApplication::installTranslator(&m_currentTranslator);
m_engine.retranslate(); // QQmlApplicationEngine
```

and i have to say that the bug is reproduced only on some machines not all...

Comment: This sounds like encoding problems. ([The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)) Could you add a minimal QML sample code to reprocude your issue ([mcve])?

Comment: Where do those strings come from, how are they set? Show the code. Does it affect all strings? "Parol'" and "Vosstanovit' Parol'" look correct to me? (as far as I can tell)

Comment: added some additional info and code

Answer (score 1):

A "Ḱ" indicates Macedonian language. So your string encoding is wrong, if you want Russian.

Quoting from the Qt docs:
"The application may occasionally require encodings other than the default local 8-bit encoding. For example, an application in a Cyrillic KOI8-R locale (the de-facto standard locale in Russia) might need to output Cyrillic in the ISO 8859-5 encoding. Code for this would be:

```
QString string = ...; // some Unicode text

QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("ISO 8859-5");
QByteArray encodedString = codec->fromUnicode(string);
```

For converting Unicode to local 8-bit encodings, a shortcut is available: the QString::toLocal8Bit() function returns such 8-bit data. Another useful shortcut is QString::toUtf8(), which returns text in the 8-bit UTF-8 encoding: this perfectly preserves Unicode information while looking like plain ASCII if the text is wholly ASCII.

For converting the other way, there are the QString::fromUtf8() and QString::fromLocal8Bit() convenience functions, or the general code, demonstrated by this conversion from ISO 8859-5 Cyrillic to Unicode conversion:

```
QByteArray encodedString = ...; // some ISO 8859-5 encoded text

QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("ISO 8859-5");
QString string = codec->toUnicode(encodedString);
```

" <sup>([[1](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the Roboto font - we changed it to the different one and everything went to normal.